# How to unpack a parsed yaml output

Tags: python, r, yaml

I have parsed a yaml file using code from another post

```
import pprint
with open("test.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    pprint.pprint(yaml.load(stream))
```

and I get the output as follows

```
 'innings': [{'1st innings': {'deliveries': [{0.1: {'batsman': 'SR Watson',
                                                'bowler': 'JM Anderson',
                                                'extras': {'wides': 1},
                                                'non_striker': 'TD Paine',
                                                'runs': {'batsman': 0,
                                                         'extras': 1,
                                                         'total': 1}}},
                                         {0.2: {'batsman': 'SR Watson',
                                                'bowler': 'JM Anderson',
                                                'non_striker': 'TD Paine',
                                                'runs': {'batsman': 0,
                                                         'extras': 0,
                                                         'total': 0}}},
                                         ...
```

How can I convert the above into a matrix/dataframe? What is the best way to do this?                                          ....

I did use R's yaml.file_load() and then coerced it into a data.frame,followed by a transpose as it had too many columns. The o/p is below

```
 innings.1st.innings.deliveries.2.3.batsman SR Watson   SR Watson
 109    innings.1st.innings.deliveries.2.3.bowler   JM Anderson JM Anderson
 110    innings.1st.innings.deliveries.2.3.non_striker  TD Paine    TD Paine
 111    innings.1st.innings.deliveries.2.3.runs.batsman 2   2
 112    innings.1st.innings.deliveries.2.3.runs.extras  0   0
 113    innings.1st.innings.deliveries.2.3.runs.total   2   2
```

I would like to perform my analysis using R. With R the column
innings.1st.innings.deliveries.2.3.runs.batsman needs to be parsed with regex and the deliveries needs to got.

Would it make sense to use perl or python and read each line finally output
something like this for

```
  Watson vs Anderson
               Runs
 Over
 1                   4
 2                   3
 3                   6

 Watson vs Broad
                   Runs
 Over
 1                   1
 2                   4
 3                   2
```

Comment: If you're using r, why aren't you using the yaml package for r?

Comment: @Patrick, I tried yaml.file_load() and I didn't like the list output. The o/p was reduced 2 long lists which would have been difficult to view and process. it makes it more easy to pre-process with Python, the o/p is easy on the eyes. I could have used sapply on the list but it went outside the screen.

Comment: you could try parsing that json in R with `jsonlite`'s `fromJSON` function, hard to say what would happen without reproducible example

Comment: @nogkrong Are you referring the the python o/p of yaml.load(stream)? Or the o/p of R using yaml.file_load()?

Comment: the o/p from python, and passing that to `fromJSON`.  This seems kindof roundabout though, there must be a good way to just read it with R's yaml parsing